# How to scrape Javascript rendered websites using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, axios

I'm trying to scrape the `$('a[href^="mailto:"]')` of this website: https://celsius.network/

When I go to the browser console and run that, I get a link so I know it's there.

The issue is that my request (using the Axios library) returns the DOM before javascript is loaded. I've set the User-Agent, but it looks like it's not working.

```
const axiosClient = () =>
  axios.create({
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A4345d Safari/600.1.4"
    },
    timeout: 10000
  });


axiosClient()
  .get("https://celsius.network")
  .then(({ data }) => {
    console.log("DATAAAAAAAA: ", data);
  })
```

This is returning the original HTML, with the body:

```
<body>
  <div id="app"> </div>
  ....
```

instead of the one that's fully loaded after all the javascript has manipulated the DOM.

P.S. I am doing this through firebase functions, so I think there are limits to what I can install.

UPDATE

```
const findEmail = url =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     // here!
  });
```

Comment: How do you get the original HTML as a response where the document is not served with CORS headers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse DOM (REACT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972996/how-to-parse-dom-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request approach isn't enough to emulate what you'd expect while visiting a page in your browser. While there are some choices out there, [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) may be a candidate for the job.

> Most things that you can do manually in the browser can be done using Puppeteer!

Check out the following...

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://celsius.network/');
  const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('a[href^="mailto:"]').textContent);

  console.log(textContent); // presale@celsius.network

  browser.close();
})();
```

I'm not totally clear on your constraints...

> there are limits to what I can install

If you have axios, I'd assume you can install this npm package?

---

Per your update, puppeteer can also be crafted via the promise api. The following should do it for you...

```
const findEmail = url =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    puppeteer.launch().then((browser) => {
      browser.newPage().then((page) => {
        page.goto('https://celsius.network/').then(() => {
          page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('a[href^="mailto:"]').textContent).then((element) => {
            resolve(element);
            browser.close();
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });

findEmail().then((email) => {
  console.log(email); // presale@celsius.network
});
```

Comment: wow I'd like to try this out! is there a way to put this inside a Promise instead of the `(async() => {})()` thing you have going

Comment: I updated the question to describe what I'm talking about with the Promise

Comment: @Edmund I have updated my answer for you, please take a look and let me know if this is what you were wanting?