# Attempting to read the HTML to find the price of XRP from my broker

Tags: html, xml, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to create a Google Apps Script that pulls a specific value from this webpage https://www.luno.com/en/price/XRP. I'm attempting to read the HTML to find the value that I'm looking for which the price of XRP from my broker, denoted as "MYR". Here's the code I'm trying to use.

```
function getXRP(){
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.luno.com/en/price/XRP').getContentText();
  var loc = html.indexOf("MYR");
  return html.substring(loc, loc+8);
}
```

From what I understand, html.indexof("MYR") is returning a value of 0, hence the output I'm getting is the first 8 characters of the websites XML

```
<!DOCTY
```

For reference, I'm trying to capture the price as below and insert it into my Google Sheets document. Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

[image: screenshot of website]

Answer (score 1):

`html.indexOf("MYR")` is returning `-1` because the source code of the page that you are fetching doesn't include `MYR`.

`UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.luno.com/en/price/XRP').getContentText()` can't be used to fetch dynamic content, instead you should find some way to create a headless browser and parse the rendered DOM instead of the source code.

Related

- [Using Apps Script to scrape javascript rendered web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50124981/1595451)
- [Is it possible to use Google Apps Script to get an info from the code I see at DevTools?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64700167/1595451)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use their API service and fetch the price: https://www.luno.com/en/developers/api#tag/Conventions

It'll be less overhead to fetch from a API than to scarp the whole webpage, parse the field by ID or name and then insert it into the spreadsheet. Fetching from API is lot easier and resource friendly.