# Google App Script: How to fix "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page"

Tags: google-apps-script

When I am using "Google App Script" in order to retrieve a json page, I face with the following message:
Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.

I am not sure how to handle this, hence I can open the same page on my web-browser.

[Q] How could I fix this in order retrieve json-page's information only using "Google App Script"?

```
function getJsonFromUrl(strUrl) {
  let _options = {
    method: 'GET',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
  };
  let _res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(strUrl, _options);
  Logger.log(_res.getContentText());
  return JSON.parse(_res.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Apps Script to scrape javascript rendered web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124981/using-apps-script-to-scrape-javascript-rendered-web-page)

Comment: no, google app script seems cannot use puppeteer

Comment: There is no other way, of course if you have time to explain to Google why this is important feature, you can try create feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: To what link are you executing the fetch? is it a javascript page?

Comment: When you track the network traffic, you will know the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment #3 and verified with the URL provided:

> There is no other way, of course if you have time to explain to Google why this is important feature, you can try create feature request here: [issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com)

You can use the following template to create the feature request:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113

Comment: yes, so sad. and will use your answer as the solution
I fix it by develop my own chromium-driver and host in cloud