# How to fix hidden div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to scrape data from **https://hordes.io/clans** with `Node.js` using `cheerio` Library, when I inspect the site it goes like this

[image: This is the pic]

But when I'm log the HTML to the console it goes like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Clans • Hordes.io</title><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="Description" content="Roam the lands in gigantic battlegroups, level up with your party, trade rare items and upgrade your gear!"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/ui/favicon32.png?v=44431023"><link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/ui/favicon16.png?v=44431023"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/clans/style.css?v=44431023"></head><body><script async src="/clans/script.js?v=44431023"></script><script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-83865980-3"></script><script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'UA-83865980-3')</script></body></html>
```

There's no `<div>` tag inside of it; how do I fix that?

Here's my code

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var drago = [];

rp('https://hordes.io/clans', function(err, resp, html) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode == 200) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var parsedResults = [];
        $('span.comhead').each(function(i, element) {
            var a = $(this).prev();
        });
        console.log(html)
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse DOM (REACT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972996/how-to-parse-dom-react)

Comment: The bulk of the page is rendered by `https://hordes.io/clans/script.js?v=44431023`

Answer (score -2):

To fix hidden div do display: block;